# Python deploying infinite while loop to production and handling failures

Tags: python, deployment, server, gunicorn

I have a script that waits for tasks from a task queue and then runs them. Something like this minimal example:

```
import redis
cache = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
import time

def main():
    while True:
        message = cache.blpop('QUEUE', timeout=0)
        work(message)

def work(message):
    print(f"beginning work: {message}")
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am not using a web server because the script does not need to answer http requests. However I've confused myself a bit about how to make this script robust against errors in production.

With a web server and gunicorn, gunicorn would handle forking a process for each request. If the request causes an error then the worker dies and the request fails but the server continues to run.

How can I achieve this if I'm not running an http server? I could fork a process to perform the "work" function, but the code performing the fork would still be application code.

Is it possible to deploy a non-http server script like mine using Gunicorn?    Is there something else I should be using to handle forking processes?
Or is it reasonable to fork inside the application and deploy to production?

Comment: You can use systemd or supervisord to launch your program and restart in case of failures

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
while True:
   try:
      message = cache.blpop('QUEUE', timeout=0)
      work(message)
   except: Exception as e :
      print(e)
```

Comment: Yeap :) It still leave error handling to the application itself. But there's so little that can go wrong there. I think. This is probably good.